# Ruby - unexpected behaviour when using &&

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

When I write the following line:

```
if (collection.respond_to? :each && collection.respond_to? :to_ary)
```

my IDE (Aptana Studio 3) gives me the following error: `, unexpected tSYMBEG`

however the error goes away if I add brackets:

```
if ((collection.respond_to? :each) && (collection.respond_to? :to_ary))
```

or change `&&` to `and`:

```
if (collection.respond_to? :each and collection.respond_to? :to_ary)
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Also what is the difference between `&&` and `and`?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` has a high [precedence](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4) (stronger than `and`, stronger than `=`).

```
foo = 3 and 5 # sets foo = 3
foo = 3 && 5  # sets foo = true
```

It's also stronger than an ambiguous function call. Your code is parsed as such

```
 if (collection.respond_to? :each && collection.respond_to? :to_ary)
 if (collection.respond_to? (:each && collection.respond_to?) :to_ary)
```

which doesn't make any sense. While using `and` is parsed as such

```
 if (collection.respond_to? :each and collection.respond_to? :to_ary)
 if (collection.respond_to?(:each) and collection.respond_to?(:to_ary))
```

I recommend that you use this one (as it doesn't rely on [operator precedence](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4) rules and uses the least braces, has shortest brace-distances, and uses `and` which are more often to be found in `if` conditions than `&&`):

```
 if collection.respond_to?(:each) and collection.respond_to?(:to_ary)
```

Comment: what about if(collecton.respond_to?(:each) && collection.respond_to?(:to_ary)) -- I believe this is also parsed correctly, am I right?

Comment: It is also parsed correctly, but you would be using unnecessary parentheses. Doing it *the Ruby way* would mean to remove optional braces unless they increase readability of your code: `if a and b` better than `if (a and b)`.

Comment: That being said, readability is subjective in many cases - there is no *wrong*. Just make sure your own coding-style remains consistent. When I started programming in Ruby I used `if (a and b)` everywhere because I programmed in C/C#/Java most of my time. Today I only use those parentheses if the condition spans over multiple lines or if precedence rules force me.

Comment: this would also work if(((collecton.respond_to?(:each) && collection.respond_to?(:to_ary)))), but also shouldnt be used :) great answer, +1. However usually when I see "and" I think of statement chaining, like how it is used in perl or bash, not boolean statements.

Answer (score 1):

Because Ruby is a dynamic language ruby has no way of knowing if you are using the symbols as integers (in which the are stored), and thus the '&&' operator has precedens over function calls, thus you are actually calling

`collection.respond_to? (:each && collection.respond_to? :to_ary)` 
instead of calling

`(collection.respond_to? :each) and (collection.respond_to? :to_ary)`

which is to method 
calls then an boolean logic operator. 
When using 'and' instead of &&, 'and' has much lower precedens (lower than function calls) and thus it also works.

['and' and 'or' vs '&&' '||'](http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)